# How to set the relative indent after breaking Python lines?

Tags: formatting, filetype-python

When I insert a line break inside a line of Python 3 code, the remaining part of the line is indented by two additional tab widths (2 time 4 spaces) in the next line.

```
# Before
example_function(argument_name_1, argument_name_2)

# After
example_function(argument_name_1,
        argument_name_2)
```

How can I change this to only one additional indent?

```
# Desired
example_function(argument_name_1,
    argument_name_2)
```

Comment: I think you should have a look to [`:h indent.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#indent.txt), I'm not a hundred percent sure but [`:h 'cindent'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cindent%27) and [`:h cinoptions-values`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values) could be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The script that controls Vim's indentation of Python files is located at `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim`. You can see the help file for it with `:help ft-python-indent`. From that, we learn there are a few global variables that can be used to control the indentation's behaviour:

> The amount of indent can be set for the following situations.  The examples
>    given are the defaults.  Note that the variables are set to an expression, so
>    that you can change the value of 'shiftwidth' later.
>
> ```
> Indent after an open paren:
>   let g:pyindent_open_paren = 'shiftwidth() * 2'
> Indent after a nested paren:
>   let g:pyindent_nested_paren = 'shiftwidth()'
> Indent for a continuation line:
>   let g:pyindent_continue = 'shiftwidth() * 2'
> ```

With this in mind, to change the behaviour to the one you intend you can add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:pyindent_open_paren = 'shiftwidth()'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using the default vim python indentation file. That's where this behavior is set, and it's pretty easy to remove. My default indentation file is located at /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/indent/python.vim. Yours might be somewhere else, but you can search for it with this command (assuming you are on a unix environment)

```
find / -name "python.vim" -type f
```

The indentation file will be in some directory probably called indent.

Anyways, relevant part of the file looks like this.

```
  " When inside parenthesis: If at the first line below the parenthesis add
  " two 'shiftwidth', otherwise same as previous line.
  " i = (a
  "       + b
  "       + c)
  " NOTE: extra lines omitted for brevity
  return indent(plnum) + (exists("g:pyindent_nested_paren") ? eval(g:pyindent_nested_paren) : shiftwidth())
      endif
      return indent(plnum) + (exists("g:pyindent_open_paren") ? eval(g:pyindent_open_paren) : (shiftwidth() * 2))
```

We will change the last line (or preferably, comment it out!) to remove the *2.

```
return indent(plnum) + (exists("g:pyindent_open_paren") ? eval(g:pyindent_open_paren) : (shiftwidth()))
```

If you don't want to mess with default files (which you probably shouldn't), you should copy the file and put it in `~/.vim/indent/python.vim`, and make your changes the the file in there. It will override the default file.

Comment: The base runtime scripts will always be at `$VIMRUNTIME`.  You can view the script with `:e $VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim`

Comment: Whoa, neat! I didn't know about this.

Comment: It is nice to see how you can override upstream scripts but the solution to set variable `g:pyindent_open_paren` is for sure the preferred one.